# How to change the input width inside a grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a form inside a grid container and I put inside each grid item a TextField.However when I change the size of the grid item ; e.g when I put xs={10} or xs={8}. the width of the TextField did not change. The reference above redirects to my reproduction example [reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/444wmr68x). I think that I made a stupid mistake but I don't know where.How can I fix that?

Comment: It is not valid to use `xs={10}` within a container with a direction of "column": https://next.material-ui.com/layout/grid/#direction-column-column-reverse (this documentation is for v4, but applies to the v3 as well). How are you wanting these text fields laid out? side-by-side or one above the other?

Comment: If you want them to take up more of the width, you can use `alignContent="stretch"` on the container Grid (along with `fullWidth` on the TextField) instead of `alignContent="center"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fullWidth` property of the material UI text field:

```
<TextField
  label="Email"
  type="email"
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
  fullWidth
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is use "fullWidth" attribute. You should change alignContent="center" to alignContent="stretch" or just remove it because "stretch" is default value of alignContent. Also, removing xs={10} email grid item.

```
<Paper className={classes.paper}>
    <Grid
        container
        justify="center"
        direction="column"
    >
        <Grid item>
            <TextField
                label="Email"
                type="email"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
            />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
            <TextField
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
            />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Paper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input would be the lower level element used in MUI and it has the properties `<Input fullwidth multiline />` that makes it stretch and if needed wrap inside the grid.